# How can I use SuperDuper! to back-up a dual SSD-HDD setup in a MBP

Tags: macos, backup, superduper

I recently bought an SSD for my MacBook Pro, which I am now using side-by-side in the MBP with the original HDD. I always used SuperDuper! to back up the hard drive. Do you know a good method to backup both drives to the same backup disk?

I have seen [this advice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT4ChaDgwnY) on YouTube, which says to make disk images of both drives, and then simply to place both of them on the backup drive. I was just wondering whether anyone would recommend a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could partition the backup disk according to the sizes of the SSD and HDD, and then clone them using SuperDuper! to the respective partitions. If your backup disk is large enough, you could also have another partition for Time Machine backups.

In the long run, it would be better for you to clone the drives to separate physical backup disks to reduce the risk of losing data due to hardware failure.

Comment: Thanks, separate drives indeed seems like the careful thing to do.